# RegEx change function name and parameter of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm awful with RegEx to begin with. Anyway I tried my best and think I got pretty far, but I'm not exactly there yet...

**What I have:** 
A javascript source file that I need to process in Node.js. Can look like that:

```
var str = "require(test < 123)\n\nrequire(test2 !== test)\n\nfunction(dontReplaceThisParam) {\n    console.log(dontReplaceThisParam)\n}";
```

**What I came up with:**

```
console.log(str.replace(/\(\s*([^)].+?)\s*\)/g, 'Debug$&, \'error_1\''))
```

**Theres a few problems:**

1. I want that the string error gets inside the paranthesis so it acts as a second parameter.
2. All function calls, or I think even everything with paranthesis will be replaced. But only function calls to "require(xxx)" should be touched.
3. Also, the error codes should somehow increment if possible...

So a string like "require(test == 123)" should convert to "requireDebug(test == 123, 'error_N')" but only calls to "require"...

**What currently gets outputted by my code:**

```
requireDebug(test < 123), 'error_1'

requireDebug(test2 !== test), 'error_1'

functionDebug(dontReplaceThisParam), 'error_1' {
    console.logDebug(dontReplaceThisParam), 'error_1'
}
```

**What I need:**

```
requireDebug(test < 123, 'error_1')

requireDebug(test2 !== test, 'error_2')

function(dontReplaceThisParam) {
    console.log(dontReplaceThisParam)
}
```

I know I could just do things like that manually but we're talking here about a few hundred source files. I also know that doing such things is not a very good way, but the debugger inside the require function is not working so I need to make my own debug function with an error code to locate the error. Its pretty much all I can do at the moment...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the regex with `require`, and since you need an incrementing counter, pass a function as the second arg to `replace`, so that you can increment and insert the counter for each match.

```js
var str = "require(test < 123)\n\nrequire(test2 !== test)\n\nfunction(dontReplaceThisParam) {\n    console.log(dontReplaceThisParam)\n}";
var counter = 0;

console.log(str.replace(/require\(\s*([^)].+?)\s*\)/g, (s, g2) => 
  `requireDebug(${g2}, \'error_${++counter}\')`
));
```

Other than that, your code was unaltered.

Comment: Holy cow! You make this look so easy * ashamed * Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, but it was easy since you wrote the majority of the regex. I just added a word. :)